# Pass an ID to OnClick event with Repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here is my screen:

[image]

Here is my code for the ItemTemplate in the Repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="float: left; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; border-style: solid; margin: 5px; background-color: Silver">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <asp:Label ID="lblImage" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "image") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="image1" Width="250px" Height="250px" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "url") %>' />
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNew" Text="New" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOriginal" Text="Original" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Repeater uses a dataset in my program to populate the ItemTemplate's label and image controls. There's another field in my dataset called `graphicID`. I'd like to, somehow, pass the value in that field to the 'Original' button, so that if a user presses that button, that particular `graphicID` is passed into the click event. Does this make sense?

For instance, the second image is Captain Harlock. The `graphicID` for this image is `93`.  If the user presses the Original button under Captain Harlock, I want to pass `93` to the `onClick` event. I'm not sure how to do this, though. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: these images are showing in dataset control which you have placed under repeater?

Comment: Not really a dataset control, but an ItemTemplate within a Repeater control.  The template contains a label, the image, and two buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @john willemse!  My question is more specific now.

Comment: then you can easily use the `CommandArgument` attribute of the button. and you can access it in item command of the repeater.

Comment: @CodeRider Thanks!  I'll read up on the CommandArgument attribute and see how to use it.  I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: your welcome. I'm editing my answer for your more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnNew" Text="New" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="cmd_original" CommandArgument="name of field which you want to access" ID="btnOriginal" Text="Original" />
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

**In repeater control**

you have to add an event as below:

```
 onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand"
```

**In code behind**

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cmd_original")
    {
        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, that is awesome!  I appreciate the extra help you've given me.  Thanks so much!