# How to get data from html column of table and pass to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a html table with data from sql. Each line has a "give" button. I need that when pressed, the value of the "code" cell is transferred to C# code. The "code" column has unique values and can be used as id.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">  
    <HeaderTemplate>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
      <th scope="col">sur</th>
      <th scope="col">code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">give</button> </th>
     
        <td><%# Eval("name")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("sur")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("code")%></td>
              
    </tr>
      </tbody>
   </itemtemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
         
   </table>

        </FooterTemplate>
    
     </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: you can make an ajax call on button's click event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656833/jquery-post-data-in-aspx-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question truly,

you can use commandArgument
But first if you dont have any **guid or Id**
you have create it in sql or frontSide, my opinion newID() in sql query is perfect
then put it in hiddenvalue or CommandArgument in frontSide.
then C# side you can handle all process in Repeater1_ItemCommand   and take data from

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "guid")
    {
        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

Also look the article
[Pass an ID to OnClick event with Repeater control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973991/pass-an-id-to-onclick-event-with-repeater-control/15974214)